# How to solve slf4j problem in selenium using java eclipse

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, log4j, pom.xml, slf4j

when I am running a simple maven based selenium java automation project then I am facing this error

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/Shivam/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/3.0.0-alpha1/log4j-slf4j-impl-3.0.0-alpha1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
Aug 17, 2023 6:45:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
Aug 17, 2023 6:45:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 115, so returning the closest version found: 114
```

> java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)

> Apache Maven 3.9.2 (c9616018c7a021c1c39be70fb2843d6f5f9b8a1c)
> Maven home: C:\maven\apache-maven-3.9.2-bin
> Java version: 20.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
> Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
> OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

I used so many maven dependency for log4j and slf4j but this error is not gone.